# Image not loading in .phtml file

Tags: magento-1.7, image, phtml, html, media

I have an image stored in `media/images`. I have a `.phtml` file that includes the following code:

```
<tr>
  <td><img src="{{media url='images/Bocadillos.png'}}" width="30" height="30"></td>
</tr>
```

but the image is not loading. I also tried

```
img src ="media/images/Bocadillos.png"
```

but it's also not working.

Which is the correct way to reference an image here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the `{{...}}` is a cms directive only used in cms/pages and cms/blocks.

If you are looking to add a specific media file to a template try:

`<?php echo $this->getUrl('pub/media') . 'path/to/url.png'; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Use below code,

```
<image src='<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'images/YOUR_IMAGE_NAME'; ?>' />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getBaseUrl` function of Mage class to get Media URL in template file.

```
<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'images/Bocadillos.png'; ?>
```

Please check [this](http://www.extensionhut.com/blog/magento-get-base-url-skin-url-media-url-js-url-store-url-and-current-url/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

`Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA)` - will return `http://[yourdomain].com/media/`.

So you can use it like this:

```
<img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA); ?>images/Bocadillos.png" />
```